# how to get TimeStamp Certificate?

Tags: itext

In order to add docuemnt the timestamp, using itext, we have com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.TSAClient abstract interface.

but how to get TimeStamp Certificate from the  PDF file?

Comment: Do you mean for signature timestamps? Or for stand-alone, document-level timestamps?

Comment: I mean document-level timestamps. I sign with TSAClient.
 LtvTimestamp.timestamp(appearance, tsa, "sig");  and then I need that certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `AcroFields` method `verifySignature` for signature fields containing document timestamps, too, and query its result for the certificates.

```
PdfReader reader = ...;
AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();
List<String> names = fields.getSignatureNames();
String signatureName = names.get(names.size() - 1);
PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.verifySignature(signatureName);
System.out.println(String.format("Checking %ssignature %s", pkcs7.isTsp() ? "document-level timestamp " : "", signatureName));
Certificate[] chain = pkcs7.getSignCertificateChain();
```

This code inspects the outermost signature or document time stamp of a document and returns that signature's or time stamp's certificate chain as far as it is known.

You might want to look at the `LtvVerifier` class (from which I extracted the code above) for verification of all signatures and document timestamps and read section 5.4.4 *Validating an LTV document* in [Digital Signatures for PDF documents](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures) for the use in context.